# rspec test that a method's input is of a certain structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec

I have a method getting input.

```
module MyModule

extend self
    def my_method(a)
      puts a
    end

end
```

I want to make sure that the method recieves a hash with keys `:a, :b and :c`

```
MyModule.should_receive(:method).with(A_HASH_WITH_KEYS(:a,:b,:c))
calling the method
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`hash_including`](http://apidock.com/rspec/Spec/Mocks/ArgumentConstraintMatchers/hash_including) in combination with [`anyhting`](http://apidock.com/rspec/Spec/Mocks/ArgumentConstraintMatchers/anything):

```
MyModule.should_receive(:method).with(
  hash_including(a: anything,b: anything,c: anything))
```

**Edit**
It seems that [newer versions](http://apidock.com/rspec/Spec/Mocks/ArgumentMatchers/hash_including) of the `hash_including` API accept array of keys, so this should also work:

```
MyModule.should_receive(:method).with(hash_including(:a, :b, :c))
```

Comment: thanks, do you know how do I validate A non empty hash?

Comment: Try `MyModule.should_not_receive(:method).with({})`

Comment: Thanks, that not what I meant. nvm, i'll open another question.